# MVC 4 Authorize attribute not recognizing forms auth from ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-3.5, authorize-attribute

I am creating a new MVC 4 app for a client that I had previously created ASP.Net 3.5 (VS 2008) apps for. I created a gateway app to launch **several other ASP.Net 3.5 web apps**, with the gateway app handling the login and the forms authentication ticket.

As long as all of the other web apps have the same settings for the forms authentication and machine key sections all other apps were able to use the forms auth objects to see if the user was authenticated.

I am now creating a new MVC 4 app using the same forms authentication settings in VS 2010 on an XP development box using IIS 5.x. (I have to do this) The problem is that the gateway app launches the MVC app fine with no login; however, if I add the Authorize attribute to initial controller the MVC app goes to the login and then the launch page as expected, however the link to the MVC app goes right back to the gateway login page.

Here are the web config sections

```
<authentication mode="Forms">   <forms
        slidingExpiration="true"
        timeout="3"
        loginUrl="http://localhost/MYGateway/Login.aspx"
        path="/"
        name=".PGSA"
        protection="All"
        defaultUrl="http://localhost/MYGateway/home.aspx"
        >   
  </forms>
```

```
<machineKey   validationKey="C5123C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D29998CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F"   validation="SHA1"   decryption="3DES"    />
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Does the machineKey match that of the gateway?  Have you tried adding the enableCrossAppRedirects attribute?  enableCrossAppRedirects="true"

Comment: yes the machine keys match, I actually pulled the config data from one of the other asp.net apps. I will try the redirects. I'll let you know how I make out. Thanks!

Comment: @Devlife - no dice on the enableCrossAppRedirects - same results.

Comment: That's too bad.  I would get the source for the AuthorizeAttribute and create a custom attribute with that source so you can step through it to see exactly where it is failing.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: FWIW I had to create a custom AuthorizeAttribute to handle SSO (like what you're doing with your gateway).

Comment: I made my own copy of the Authorize attribute and I was able to inspect the request - the cookie that I created in my gateway app is not there. I checked one of the other 3.5 apps using the IE dev tool and I can see it is there. So the cookie never gets to the MVC 4 app.

Comment: You might want to fire up Fiddler2 and inspect the request from the browser perspective to make sure the browser is sending the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to get this solved, thanks to this question's second answer by James H [Upgrading to ASP.NET 4.5/MVC 4 forms authentication fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021863/upgrading-to-asp-net-4-5-mvc-4-forms-authentication-fails)

The trick is this

```
<system.web>
 <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" /> 
</system.web>
```